# Angular Ionic Capacitor Barcode Scanner Plugin not working on Web

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am currently building my first Ionic app, which should include a QR-Code scanner.

This is my package.ts

```
{
  "name": "drink-inc",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.4",
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.3.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^13.0.0-beta.38",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.2",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/barcode-scanner": "^5.41.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.5.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.1.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.5.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.4",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.2.2",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.8",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.0.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.11",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^13.2.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.2.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.2.2",
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.5.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

So i wanted to add the [Cordova Barcode Scanner Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner) via Capacitor.

At first i installed the plugin, like the guide describes:

```
$ npm install phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 
$ npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/barcode-scanner 
$ ionic cap sync
```

After that implemented a very basic version of the barcode scanner:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import { BarcodeScanner } from "@awesome-cordova-plugins/barcode-scanner/ngx";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "./home.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["./home.page.scss"],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner
  ) {}

  joinBarcodeRoom() {
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

After that i had to include the `BarcodeScanner` in the providers Array of my `app.component.module` and it worked perfectly fine on the android emulator.

Hovewer, running the code in the browser generates the following error:

```
Native: tried calling BarcodeScanner.scan, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
core.mjs:6485 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1262:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1216:1)
    at zone.js:1329:1
    at _ZoneDelegate.push.3484._ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:443:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25535:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.push.3484._ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:442:1)
    at Zone.push.3484.Zone.runTask (zone.js:214:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:632:1)
    at ZoneTask.push.3484.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:529:1)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1714:1)
```

Is there a way to fix this error?
If I have to include Cordova, isn't that bad for performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capacitor doesn’t support cordova plugins on web, only on iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1):

Since You have added awesome cordova plugin You have to added it to app.module.ts provider array.

```
import { BarcodeScanner } from "@awesome-cordova-plugins/barcode-scanner/ngx";
...
providers:[BarcodeScanner]
```

Comment: I already did that...

Comment: Check this link may help You.   https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/decode-qr-code-in-browser/78116/9